# Проверка валидности url. PHP

Tags: php

Я нарыл такое:

```
$a = 'http://site.ru';
if (preg_match('/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]{1,3}+[.][0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+[.][0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]{2,6}+$/', $a)) echo "yes";
else echo "no";
```

Но эта штука все время выдает "no". Мне кажется это из за кириллицы. Ее убирать нельзя. сайт.рф ведь... Помогите пожалуйста, как исправить. Я работаю в кодировке UTF-8

---

Вот нарыл по-лучше, но не могу кириллицу добавить.. Помогите плиз

```
function is_url($in){ 
    $w = "a-z0-9"; 
    $url_pattern = "#( 
    (?:f|ht)tps?://(?:www.)? 
    (?:[$w\\-.]+/?\\.[a-z]{2,4})/? 
    (?:[$w\\-./\\#]+)? 
    (?:\\?[$w\\-&=;\\#]+)? 
    )#xi";

    $a = preg_match($url_pattern,$in); 
    return $a; 
}
```

Comment: Дайте URL для примера или вы проверяете на валидность URN (т.е. просто доменное имя?)

Comment: http://site.ru/cat/page.php?get=one&get1=two#hash

Также http://сайт.рф/cat/page.php?tag=тег&get1=второй#hash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для проверки url [советую](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) :

`filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)`

В плане проверки русскоязычных доменов могу рекомендовать смотреть в сторону конвертации в IDN, т.е. к виду `xn--af1bc.net` тогда проблем с русским точно не будет.
В стандартном наборе таких функций нет, только декодирование. Если есть возможность поставить соответствующий модуль PECL, то на мой взгляд это идеальное решение.

Comment: Пробовал конверктацию IDN - выдает false. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам надо проверить, существует ли указанный адрес или нет, то есть способ гораздо проще:

```
$url = 'http://hashcode.ru';
if(get_headers($url, 1)){
   echo 'Гуд';
}
```

Потому, как http://www.chopopalo.com - проверку регуляркой пройдет, но вот сайта такого, просто не существует.

Comment: Нет, мне нужно проверить, в верном ли формате ссылка

Comment: То есть вам без разницы, существует такой адрес или отбалды написали? Тогда смотрите ответ @Gedweb

Comment: только перед таким смелым запросом я бы добавил `if(checkdnsrr($domain,'A') && get_headers($url, 1))` что бы не получить ошибку.

Автор, думаю это действительно самый подходящий вариант

Comment: На самом деле это не нужно. Это много пользовательский сайт, и пользователи сами должны беспокоится о существовании сайта по указываемой ссылке

Comment: Тему развезли, а реального решения так и не нашли. Вариант с IDN бы рассмотреть

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, ну вы бы еще в спортлото письмо с жалобой написали.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще не встречал адекватных регулярок для проверки url. Так что для таких случаев нужно четко формировать требования к урлу, а потом уже составлять выражение.

`$a` у Вас не соответствует выражению, в то время как "http://www.site.ru" - вполне подойдет. А вот "http://subdomen.site.ru" - уже не влезет. Если урл еще ведет на внутреннюю страницу - тоже не подходит. А зачастую главными являются страницы вида "http://site.ru/en/index.html". И т.д. И т.п.

С русским языком проблем быть не должно, а если всё-таки возникают - значит у Вас старое ПО, пропишите в регулярку весь алфавит.

[Регулярное выражение сложных URL](http://softtime.ru/forum/read.php?id_forum=6&id_theme=81361)

Comment: Требование самое сложное)) URL с GET параметрами и hash'ами. Я обновил шапку и ф-ия, которую добавил удовлетворяет всем моим требованиям, но я не могу добавить кириллицу. Прошу помощи :)

Comment: Неа. Кириллицу не пускает

Comment: Если не пускает кириллицу - значит, как я уже говорил, проблемы с ПО. Пропишите весь русский алфавит.

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_url($url) {
    return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
```

Comment: В шапке вариант вроде по-лучше. Но может вы сможете помочь кириллицу добавить для проверки "сайт.рф" и подобного?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно проверить ссылку с протоколом или без протокола:

```
$url = 'кто.рф';
if (preg_match("/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)*[а-яА-ЯёЁa-z0-9\-_]+(\.[а-яА-ЯёЁa-z0-9\-_]+)+(\/\S*)*$/iu", $url) ) {
  echo 'true';
}
else echo 'false';
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // начать объяснение можно, например, с аргументации, почему в диапазон вы включили прописные буквы кириллицы, но не включили прописные буквы латиницы.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTransliterations($msg) {
    $rus = array(
        'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М',
        'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ',
        'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з',
        'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х',
        'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я');
    $lat = array(
        'A', 'B', 'V', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'Gh', 'Z', 'I', 'Y', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
        'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'Ch', 'Sh', 'Sch',
        'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'E', 'Yu', 'Ya', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'gh', 
        'z', 'i', 'y', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f',
        'h', 'c', 'ch', 'sh', 'sch', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'e', 'yu', 'ya');
    return str_replace($rus, $lat, $msg);
}

$host = 'https://ярусский.рф';

echo !filter_var(getTransliterations($host), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ? false : true;
```

Можно переведите русские символы в английские. Тем более, как понял, в вопросе про доступность сайта не спрашивается, формат пройдёт и ладно.